# Google sheet script, times out. Need a new way or flip it upside down

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

noob here, so the script works great if there are less than 800 rows on a sheet, however this time I have a sheet of almost 1500 rows and the script times out.

Basically it is a quick way to get a quote. (quick here means 5-6mins, not an issue) It hides columns with calculations, hides columns with sensitive information and rows where there was no value in column H.

What I want to know is, if I can do the same with a different code, or if someone knows how to make getRange().getValue(); start at the bottom of the sheet, then I could have two scripts starting one after the other to finish the sheet and produce a printable quote.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

here is the script:

```
function Quote()
{ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Quote"); `


  var datarange = s.hideColumns(6);
  var datarange = s.hideColumns(9);
  var datarange = s.hideColumns(10);
  var datarange = s.hideColumns(12);
  var datarange = s.hideColumns(13);
  var datarange = s.hideColumns(14);

  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
  for( i=1 ; i<=lastRow ; i++) {

       var status = s.getRange("H"+i).getValue();
       if (status == "") { 
         s.hideRows(i);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is row:

```
s.getRange("H"+i).getValue()
```

This code takes data from spreadsheet, this is very slow process when you use it inside loop. You may use this conctruction:

```
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var status = data[i][7]; // takes column H          
      // other code goes here...          
  }
```

This way you read data from the spreadsheet only once using `getDataRange()`, and convert it into array with `getValues()`. Then loop should work way more faster.

When hiding rows, remember to add 1 because array starts from 0, heres code for hiding rows inside loop:

```
   if (status == "") { 
     s.hideRows(i + 1); // adding 1
  }
```