# Google Sheet Script - Multiple getRange looping

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

so I have a new problem.

So far my script here can loop a sheet and find the text "Bank", it will set the background color to red and it will take the value from another cell as marked and log it. Once it have done that once it will crash, so the loop will break, I have no idea why?

```
function sortBank() { 
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
      var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
      var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
      var values = rows.getValues(); 
      var rowsDeleted = 0

      for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { 
        var row = values[i]; 
        if (row[8].indexOf('Bank') > -1) { /** Set the Job prefix **/

          sheet.getRange(parseInt(i)+1,9).setBackgroundColor("#f44336");
          var values = sheet.getRange(parseInt(i),2).getValues();

          Logger.log(values[0][0]);

        } 
      } 
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look at similar questions:

[Google Script - Internal Error after 15 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859421/google-script-internal-error-after-15-seconds)

[Google script - Exceeded maximum execution time , help optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586911/google-script-exceeded-maximum-execution-time-help-optimize/39588156#39588156)

[Google sheet script, times out. Need a new way or flip it upside down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618266/google-sheet-script-times-out-need-a-new-way-or-flip-it-upside-down/38630003#38630003)

Basic solution is to use `getValues()` one time and then loop values in 2d array:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
var data = rows.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
{
  var j = SomeValue; // column number - 1
  var row = data[i]; // row from origonal data range
  var value = row[j]; // value from data
  // some other code...   
}
```

See more info about your problem [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices):

> Your scripts will run faster if you can find ways to minimize the
>   calls the scripts make to those services.

Comment: Ah, so it's due to the script taking to long to run?

Comment: I think so, because there is `getValues()` inside a loop .