# For Loops timing out: JavaScript / Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am have this issue with Google Apps Script. It is timing out because the app server requests are taking too long. I was just wanting to see if my coding could be cleaned up a bit to run faster or is there another method which would work?

Code below:

```
for (var y = 1; y < listLast ; y++) {

  var matchor = listSheet.getRange("B" + y).getValue();
  var listEmCo = listSheet.getRange("A" + y).getValue();
  if(matchor == "Match") {
    Logger.log("Do Nothing");
  } else {
  for (var x = 0; x < formLast; x++) {

  if(listEmCo == formData[x]){

    listSheet.getRange("B"+ [y]).setValue("Match");
    break;

  } else {

    listSheet.getRange("B"+ [y]).setValue("No Match");

   }
  }
 }   
}
```

Thanks for any responses :)

Comment: What are the values of listLast and formLast? Could they be the reason for infinite loops?

Comment: Them values are either their email address or "match" or "not match"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `.getValue();` in a loop. This operation is heavy.

Please use `range.getValues()` and then loop the array to get values.

The plan is:

1. get the initial `range`
2. get data with `var data = range.getValues();`
3. make empty array to write new values `array = [];`
4. Loop the data and make new array, fill it with proper values `[["value1"], ["value2"], ...,]`. **Note.** It should be a 2D-Array.
5. After the loop define a range to paste new values: `rangeTo`
6. Use `rangeTo.setValues(array);` to paste new values.

See more:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices
- https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2017/11/02/scripts-working-with-arrays-in-sheets/

## Tag #Another-get-data-from-range-question

See more questions on topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859421/google-script-internal-error-after-15-seconds

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586911/google-script-exceeded-maximum-execution-time-help-optimize

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618266/google-sheet-script-times-out-need-a-new-way-or-flip-it-upside-down

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021567/google-sheet-script-multiple-getrange-looping

[Code runs too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512605/google-apps-script-code-runs-too-slow)